# Not waking up more than once?

Tags: c, interrupt, sleep

I'm trying the following code on an Uno. I'm pulling the high side of a pull down 10K resistor to 5V, but it can only be woken once. Just once. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

It works fine if I use `LOW` for `attachInterrupt` along with a pull-up resistor though. Just not with `RISING` and a pull-down.

```
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/power.h>

int pin2 = 2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  /* Setup the pin direction. */
  pinMode(pin2, INPUT);

  Serial.println("Initialisation complete.");

}

void pin2Interrupt(void)
{
  /* This will bring us back from sleep. */

  /* We detach the interrupt to stop it from 
   * continuously firing while the interrupt pin
   * is high.
   */
  detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin2));
}

void enterSleep(void)
{  

  sleep_enable();

  /* Setup pin2 as an interrupt and attach handler. */
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin2), pin2Interrupt, RISING);
  delay(100);

  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);

  sleep_mode();

  /* The program will continue from here. */

  /* First thing to do is disable sleep. */
  sleep_disable(); 
}

int seconds=0;
void loop()
{
  delay(1000);
  seconds++;

  Serial.print("Awake for ");
  Serial.print(seconds, DEC);
  Serial.println(" second");

  if(seconds >= 3)
  {
    Serial.println("Entering sleep");
    delay(200);
    seconds = 0;
    enterSleep();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I have seen somewhere in the past a problem with detaching an interrupt from within an interrupt handler.  You shouldn't need to detach and attach the interrupt handler all the time - just leave it attached.

Comment: @Majenko But you wouldn't want interrupts to keep firing whilst it's going to sleep, right?

Comment: I don't understand that question.  What do you mean by "going to sleep"? It's either asleep or awake. You need interrupts enabled while it's asleep so you can wake up. Does it really matter to you if an empty interrupt handler gets triggered if you press the button while it's awake?

Comment: Based on the examples [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/ArduinoSleepCode), it says "In the interrupt service routine (ISR) for a level interrupt, the interrupt must be detached otherwise the interrupt will keep happening and the ISR will be repeatedly called until the pin changes state." So it sounds like it's essential to detach - no?

Comment: Read the last word in your attachInterrupt call.  What does it say?

Comment: You mean `RISING`? Yeah, I'm trying to pull the pin high rather than low.

Comment: That means that the pin has to *transition from low to high* to trigger the interrupt.  It only does it at the moment the pin changes, not all the time it's HIGH. You have an EDGE interrupt, not a LEVEL interrupt. It will only trigger once per press of the button (discounting bounces).

Comment: Indeed. However, AFAIK, the Uno doesn't not support the `HIGH` argument. Is there an alternative? My chip pulls the interrupt high, so I thought `LOW` wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: You are using the alternative! RISING means TRIGGER ONCE WHEN IT RISES which is what you want WITHOUT having to manually disable the interrupt!

Comment: `I'm pulling the high side of a pull down 10K resistor to 5V, but it can only be woken once. ` - you mean you are pulling it **up**, right?

Comment: @NickGammon Sorry. Yes, that's right.

Comment: So, really on a rising interrupt you want to put the 10k resistor to ground, yes? That's what I did in my test below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `RISING` interrupt you never need to disconnect the interrupt to prevent repeat triggering.

A `RISING` interrupt specifically only triggers the once when the input pin transitions from `LOW` to `HIGH` rather than all the time it's in a state like a *level* interrupt.

Attach the interrupt once in setup() and leave it alone after that.  Your interrupt handler routine can be completely empty.  It will only ever be triggered at the exact moment you press the button.  To trigger it again you will just need to press the button again.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your switch is bouncing and giving two interrupts. The first wakens it, and the second is lying there waiting until you attach the interrupt again. Then it fires, detaches the interrupt, then you go to sleep, never to awaken.

Clear any pending interrupt **before** doing the attachInterrupt:

```C++
EIFR = bit (INTF0);  // clear flag for interrupt 0
```

See [Interrupts](http://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts).

It is also wise to have interrupts off while setting up for sleep.

---

Example code:

```C++
#include <avr/sleep.h>                  

const byte LED = 13;

// interrupt service routine in sleep mode
void wake ()
{
  sleep_disable ();         // first thing after waking from sleep
}  // end of wake

void sleepNow ()
{
  set_sleep_mode (SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);   
  noInterrupts ();          // make sure we don't get interrupted before we sleep
  sleep_enable ();          // enables the sleep bit in the mcucr register
  EIFR = bit (INTF0);       // clear flag for interrupt 0
  attachInterrupt (0, wake, RISING);  // wake up on rising edge
  interrupts ();           // interrupts allowed now, next instruction WILL be executed
  sleep_cpu ();            // here the device is put to sleep
  detachInterrupt (0);      // stop this interrupt until next time
}  // end of sleepNow

void setup ()
  {
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {
  sleepNow ();
  digitalWrite (LED, HIGH);
  delay (1000);
  digitalWrite (LED, LOW);
  }  // end of loop
```

Tested and works OK.

---

Note: Since this is a rising interrupt you should have a **pull-down** resistor on the pin, and you trigger the interrupt by connecting the pin to +5 V.